# Will the Probe in "The Inner Light" Work for Others?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In *The Inner Light*, at the end of the story, the probe that was communicating with Captain Picard (and showing him the way of life for a now dead civilization).  The intent of the probe was to say to someone else, "We were here and this is what life was like for us.  Don't forget us."

But the probe only reached out to one person and once it finished the program, it stopped communicating with Picard.

Was the experience Picard went through a one time thing?  Is there anything (even in the Expanded Universe) to indicate that others could experience the same program, or was the probe only capable of sending the message and running the program once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the probe stopped working at the end of the transmission to Picard. Riker visits Picard at the end of the episode, bringing the only one thing of value they found on the probe: the flute. He mentions during his report that the probe seemed to have destroyed its "electronics" and they could not find out how it did what it did to Picard. Thus it would not work for others again.

While experiencing the memories stored in the probe Picard witnesses the start of the (one) rocket carrying the probe into space. This means there are no other probes in the universe to carry the message.